# Determining a unique identifier name using Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, roslyn

Using Roslyn, I'm generating C# code based on a method symbol parsed from code outside of my control. Therefore, the method could have any number of arguments. The code I generate includes a lambda expression that takes a single argument, such as:

```
// I'm generating code like this
public void SomeMethod()
{
    DoSomething(x => x.Foo());
}
```

A potential problem with this code is if the containing method includes a parameter called `x`:

```
// my code generator might produce this
public void SomeMethod(int x)
{
    DoSomething(x => x.Foo());
}
```

This code results in an error:

> A local or parameter named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Fair enough.

To get around this, I was thinking I could start with the identifier name `x`, use `SemanticModel.LookupSymbols` to see whether it's already defined. If so, prepend `_` (to get `_x`) and repeat.

But is this the best way? And if so, how do I use `LookupSymbols` when all I have is a method symbol?

Another option I thought of was to just use the `Parameters` collection in the method symbol. I could perform the same name selection algorithm against them instead. But would this suffice? For example:

```
private static string GetIdentifierName(IMethodSymbol within)
{
    var proposed = "x";

    while (within.Parameters.Any(x => x.Name == proposed))
    {
        proposed = "_" + proposed;
    }

    return proposed;
}
```

Comment: When I had to verify against method parameter identifiers, I used your second approach as well.

Comment: You also need to check locals.

Comment: @Slaks: I'm generating the method, so I'm in control of the locals (there are none).

Answer (score 1):

Using the `SemanticModel.LookupSymbols` seems like a good approach. This is the way Visual Studio moves selected code to new methods. Check out the [`UniqueNameGenerator`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/ExtractMethod/UniqueNameGenerator.cs,f9fccab13739c5bb) internal class in Roslyn.

As for how to use `LookupSymbols` when all you have is a method symbol: you already add your generated `DoSomething(x => x.Foo());` to the code, so you have more than just a method symbol, don't you? But in any case, from an `IMethodSymbol` you can get the [`DeclaringSyntaxReferences`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs,7f9fc305c0940c9b,references) to access the corresponding syntax nodes.